# How to have a Delegate as a default parameter in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I am building a text-based menuing system for a personal project. An option on that menu would have text and an action(method call). So I thought it made sense to use delegates.

So I tried to use a Delegate as an optional parameter for addOption() and I got the error

> Error Default parameter value for 'optionAction' must be a compile-time constant

So I am not exactly sure how to get around this. I mean it says it must be a compile time constant. I don't logically see any possibility of my method defaultod() changing at compile time, but Visual Studio does so I need a workaround if possible.

This is a sample of my code in question. And I would be glad to show more upon request.

```
private delegate void defaultOption();
private void defaultOptionCall() { }

public void addOption(string optiontext,
                      Delegate optionAction = new defaultOption(defaultOptionCall))
{

}
```

Comment: Why `ref Delegate`? Do you plan on changing the calling delegate from within the method?

Comment: The only valid compile-time constant here is *null*.  So just check for null in the method body.  Fuggedaboutit when you actually need *ref*.

Comment: _error CS1741: A ref or out parameter cannot have a default value_ What did you expect the combination of `ref` and default value to do? What should be passed by-ref if the caller omitted the argument?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't understand what `ref` means based on the context here. Probably that would be a good thing to learn before you go further. `ref` makes an alias to a variable; delegates are already passed by reference.

Comment: Also, this code is very strange; why `Delegate` and not some more specific delegate type like `defaultOption`? This is like taking `Array` or `Enum` instead of a specific array type or specific enum type. Almost no one does this; what's your purpose in doing so here?

Comment: The reason for Delegate instead of a specific type of Delegate was that it the menu's options if picked would do various things which could be represented by a large variety of method signatures. Forcing it to only accept just 1 type of method signature would make other aspects of the project more complicated and less organized.

Comment: My apologies to all for my absent-mindedness about ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend to use `Action` since it's the same idea but easier syntax and implementation...

```
public void addOption(string optiontext, Action optionAction = null)
{
    if (optionAction == null)
    {
        defaultOptionCall();
        // whatever else you need
        return;
    }

    // to run the action
    optionAction.Invoke();
}
```

This allows you to pass a string and a method of your choosing and having it execute unless it's null without fussing with `ref`. Though technically `Action` itself is a form of delegation as already implied. Sample use cases...

```
addOption("default");
addOption("hello", () => { Console.WriteLine("Hello!") });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `new` keyword in an expression, it is obviously not a constant expression. *(As Eric Lippert says in his comment, specifying basic value types like `int` with `new int()` is considered as being a constant expression. Not very intuitive.)*. Delegates are not considered being compile time constants. The only option is to use `null`.

```
public delegate void DefaultOption();

private void DefaultOptionCall() { }

public void AddOption(string optiontext, DefaultOption optionAction = null)
{
    DefaultOption action = optionAction ?? DefaultOptionCall;
    ...
}
```

The coalesce operator `??` yields the second term if the first one is `null` and otherwise the first one.

And also, since `DefaultOption` is used in the declaration of a public method, it has to be public as well. And optional parameters cannot be by reference.

Finally the .NET naming conventions say that method names and type names (like delegate types) should start with an upper case letter. The C# aliases of standard types are an exception to this rule.

Comment: Though your answer is correct -- there are no constant expressions of reference type other than literal strings and null references -- it is not necessarily *obvious* that a "new" expression is not a constant expression. `new int()` is a legal constant expression. Extremely weird, but legal.

Comment: This is the "canonical" answer. Remember however, that in .NET the value `null` for a multicast delegate is "legitimate" since (for some reason) it represents the delegate with empty invocation list. So with this solution, we can't pass in a `null` where we mean `null`. The asker might as well choose to drop the default parameter approach and make two overloads instead. (Sometimes it feels unfortunate that .NET cannot distinguish between an "empty" multicast delegate and "absence" of a multicast delegate (`null`). In the same way as `int[] a = { };` and `int[] a = null;` can be distinguished.)

Comment: You are right, but the question is whether there are really situations where this makes any difference, since, before invoking delegates, you have to make sure they are not `null` anyway. (Especially when working with events.)

Comment: This is very close to what I want, but I was trying get it able to accept nearly any type of method call. Not just private void no parameter methods.

Comment: If you allow any type of method call, which values would you pass for the parameters? I see two possibilities: 1) Either you have a parameter-less method or, 2) a method where you can pass information regarding the menu item that was clicked. Where would you get other parameters from?

Answer (score 2):

You should use method overloading instead:

- `AddOption(String)` => This would do the whole default action and no delegate would be required because you know what you need in advance.
- `AddOption(String, Delegate)`

Anyway, why don't you use `Action` instead of `Delegate`?

In the other hand, why you want to use `ref` keyword if `Delegate` is a reference type *as is*? I believe that it's useless in your case.

Comment: Actually, sometimes it's the easy things one misses... it's a matter of style, but I like this better than fiddling with null and using a default inside the function. (Of course the "default" version then calls the explicit one, with a default delegate.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Absolutely... In fact, optional parameters weren't introduced to replace method overloading... C# isn't JavaScript or other languages lacking overloading..